# How to find whether Google Maps API is licensed or not?

Tags: javascript, licenses, google-map

I am using Google maps API in my salesforce application. I am using this javascript file  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places to integrate my application with google maps.

Usually with google, a key should be used to access this API. The idea is that this API is not free and we should license this, we may be using a development version but this version is limited based on number of calls and requests.

I looked into the javascript file, also in the controller class but was not able to determine or find the key. 
I just want to find out are we using a licensed version or free ?

Comment: Sus, how is this related to salesforce technologies (the subject of this site) ? I'm closing this as off-topic, as it appears to be purely about google and it's api's and is therefore better asked at a forum about google or programming in general (stackoverflow). If there's a connection to salesforce that isn't obvious to me, do please edit your question and ask for it to be opened again.

Comment: I am using google API in my salesforce application and therefore I posted this question here.

Comment: I can understand that, but the question itself is about google and it's API's,  for which you may better consult a forum more specific to those technologies.  Salesforce is compatible with 100's of 3th party libraries  in it's HTML front end, it's not an aim of this community to answer all those questions here. With your same login you have access to our "origin-website" stackoverflow.com which may be a better fit.

Comment: Its a free version !

Answer (score 1):

Do you have lines like the following in your code?

```
<!-- Set this API key to fix JavaScript errors in production -->
<!--http://salesforcesolutions.blogspot.com/2013/01/integration-of-salesforcecom-and-google.html-->
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=ABCDEFC-ASDFASFASFSADFSADF12341234&sensor=false"> 
    </script>
```

If so, then you've got a key.  If this code block is commented out, then you don't have a key.  If you don't see a map when you try to work with Google Maps, then you most likely don't have a key.

This code came from the Salesforce1 warehouse example.  That example seems to work without a key (if you're lucky) for a few days.  After that, the map doesn't show up.  Uncommenting this code block and adding a key will bring it back

Note: not my real key.

Comment: Hi Jagular, I looked at my javascript file and see that I don't have that key mentioned (the way u showed here) so if I go according to what u said it means I don't have license because I don't have key. Now, your other statement says that the map doesn't show up. I am working from the past 3 months but I could still see the map. What does this mean ? Do I have license ?

Comment: I should have mentioned that my code sample was from a Visualforce page.  It's possible your code is organized differently.